# Angularjs ng-show isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Why isn't my container showing when I set selectedManager via an ng-click?

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="manager in allManagers" ng-click="openDetails(manager)">
<div class="container" ng-show="selectedManager">
```

JS:

```
$scope.selectedManager;
$scope.openDetails = function(item) {
  selectedManager = item;
  console.log(selectedManager);
}
```

Console.log prints the object successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall modify `$scope.selectedManager` property:

```
$scope.openDetails = function (item) {
    $scope.selectedManager = item;
    console.log(selectedManager);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

This is so because in your code:

```
$scope.selectedManager;
$scope.openDetails = function(item){
selectedManager=item;
console.log(selectedManager);
}
```

You are assigning value to **selectedManager**, which is a local variable and not scope variable **$scope.selectedManager**

To make it work you either use `$scope.selectedManager` in place of `selectedManager`

OR

assign `$scope.selectedManager=item` directly

local variables are not accessible in HTML, only scope variable are.